# How do I bind to Canvas.Left or Canvas.Top attached property in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a `UserControl` that is draggable in a `Canvas`. I am brand new to `MVVM` and relatively new to `WPF` (also pretty new to StackOverflow).

I have a view model, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, for the new `UserControl` that has properties called "Top" and "Left". I would like to bind the Top and Left properties of my view model to the attached `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` of the `UserControl`. For reasons I won't get into, I can't use any `XAML`.

This is how I've implemented my Left (and similarly Top) properties (not sure how to make code highlighting work yet):

```
public class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // . . .
    double _left;
    public double Left 
    { 
        get { return _left; }
        set
        {
            if(_left != value)
            {
                _left = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Left");
            }
        }
    }
    // . . .
}
```

This is how I've implemented my 'UserControl':

```
public class FooControl : UserControl
{
    // . . .
    private FooViewModel _vm;

    public FooControl(FooViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
        this.DataContext = _vm;

        Binding b = new Binding("Left");
        b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        this.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, b);

        // . . .
    }
    // . . .
}
```

To test, I have manually created some view model instances, set the Left and Top properties on them, created instances of my `UserControl` by passing these to the constructor, and added them to a 'Canvas'. Unfortunately, all of my added controls show up in the top-left corner of the 'Canvas' and the debugger shows that while the Top and Left properties of the view model are set correctly, calling `Canvas.GetLeft(...)` and `Canvas.GetTop(...)` on the controls return `NaN`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I taking the wrong approach?

I've tried to base my code around this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545394/binding-the-position-and-size-of-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas-in-wpf).

EDIT:
Actually, this does work! I had mistake in my code where the `UserControl` wasn't getting a proper reference to an instance of the view model. Once I hooked that up correctly it worked fine. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I tried to base my solution on the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545394/binding-the-position-and-size-of-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas-in-wpf), which I think implements basically what I want in `XAML`. There they mentioned that the `TwoWay` mode allows the data source (my view model) to get updated when the user moves the control in the canvas (eventually I intend for these to be draggable).

Comment: @Pysul: That depends on the implementation of that dragging, would just edit the VM in that case as well instead of the canvas properties.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you add the controls to the Canvas. I just made a quick sample using your code and it works fine, so I believe its a problem somewhere else, in code you haven't provided above.

Comment: I will try to post more complete code tomorrow when I get back to my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code should work just fine.

Are the controls actually *immediate* children of the canvas? If not it will not work.

Comment: You were right, it does work! Looking at the debugger with fresh eyes this morning I noticed that user control wasn't getting hooked up to the view model correctly due to a typo in its constructor (whoops!).

Thank you all for the help--your confirmation that the code should work kept me on track rather than trying to solve a non-existent problem.